# How to determine which View was clicked in a ListView while handling ListView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with three TextViews:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtOPrice"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOPrice"
        android:text="1.60"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtNetPrice"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNetPrice"
        android:text="1.61"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm handling the ListView item click event as follows:

```
    adapter = new productListAdapter(this,arrayListProducts);
    listProducts.setAdapter(adapter);

    listProducts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //how to know which textview was clicked?
        }
    });
```

I just want to know how can I determine which TextViews were clicked?

I'm a novice, searched a lot but found nothing.

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the callback, the `view` parameter is the clicked view item, and `i` is the position in your listview. However, `view` is a reference to the whole list item, meaning the `RelativeLayout` in your case. From there you can find the specific TextView that you need using `findViewById()` on the view parameter, this will return you the desired TextView within the list item

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However what I'm asking is this: If user clicks on one particular textview I need to run a particular bunch of code and if user clicks on another I need to run a different code. So how to determine which TextView in the RelativeLayout was actually clicked.

Comment: In that case onItemClickListener is not what you're looking for. You'll need to set 3 different onClickListener to each textview, and you can set a tag using `setTag` to each of these textviews, therefore you can identify them

Answer (score 0):

You can set on click listener on all the 3 textviews of layout as well as set the tag to all the views. So by using tag and id u can get which view is clicked.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: View v = ((View) findViewbyid(R.id.txtProductName)); v.setOnclickListener(this); 
v.setTag(pos);                                                                          onClick(View v)
 {
 switch (v.getId())
{ 
case R.id.txtProductName:
doprodTask(v.getTag())
}      

  doProdTask(Position)
{
 }

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use listview with custom adapter and add clicklistners to each of the textview.

Comment: I need to handle the click events in my activity and not in the adapter class. And I'm already using a custom adapter class.

Comment: When there is will there is way. You can add an inner class to your activity.